# Borrar multiples filas con PHP (PDO, POO) y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Estoy intentando borrar multiples filas a travez de un checkbox, busque mucho e incluso utilice chatGPT pero no consigo solucionarlo, me borra una sola fila pero cuando selecciono varias no lo hace. Para acceder a ellas estuve utilizando setters y getters.

Este es el codigo:

productClass.php

```
 //Method to delete in database
public function deleteProduct()
{
    try{
        $stm= $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM product WHERE sku IN (?)");
        $stm->execute([$this->sku]);
        return $stm->fetchAll();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Index.php (donde se visualiza y esta el checkbox)

```
<form action="product/delete.php" method="post" id="product_list">
<?php 
  require_once("product/productClass.php");
  $take = new Product();
  $product = $take->showAll();
  foreach ($product as $key => $prod):?>
  <div class="col-sm-2 border border-dark my-5 container-fluid shadow">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteSku[]" id="delete-checkbox" value="<?= $prod['sku']?>">
    <h5 class="text-center"><?= $prod['sku']?></h5>
    <p class=" text-center"><?= $prod['name']?></p>
    <p class=" text-center"><?= $prod['price']?>$</p>
    <p class=" text-center">
    <?php echo $prod['size'] != 0 ? "Size: " . $prod['size'] . " " ."MB" : '';

          echo $prod['weight'] != 0 ? "Weight: " . $prod['weight'] . " " . "KG" : '';

          echo $prod['height'] && $prod['width'] && $prod['length'] != 0 ? "Dimensions: " . $prod['height']."x".$prod['width']."x".$prod['length'] : "" ; ?> </p>

<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete" id="delete-product-btn">MASS DELETE</button>

  </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </form>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
require_once("productClass.php");
$take = new Product();

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
  if(isset($_POST['deleteSku']) && is_array($_POST['deleteSku']))
  {
    foreach ($_POST['deleteSku'] as $record);
    $take->setSku($record);
    $take->deleteProduct();
    header("location:../index.php");
  }

}


?>
```

Espero que se entienda que es lo que quiero hacer, cualquier ayudita me sirve.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si `$this->sku` es un array, en PDO no puedes enlazar esa estructura con el identificador directamente. El problema está en estas líneas:

```php
$stm = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM product WHERE sku IN (?)");
$stm->execute([$this->sku]);
```

Tienes que crear un identificador `?` por cada elemento del array. Entonces, para resolverlo se puede generar una cadena de tantos `?` como elementos contenga:

```php
// $array_sku ==> array de ids obtenido de $this->sku
$arr_ids = str_repeat('?,', count($array_sku) - 1) . '?';
$stm = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM product WHERE sku IN ($arr_ids)");
$stm->execute($array_sku);
```

Comment: Me tiro el siguiente error: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array. Luego de agregar un array al contador se soluciono pero me sigue agregando 1 en vez de todos los seleccionados

Comment: @David es porque en `$stm->execute()` también tiene que ir un array. No noté que ya habían unos paréntesis `[]`, así que quedaba un array dentro de otro. Edité la respuesta con las correcciones.